# Why is Tokyo Ghoul's second season called √A?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

As the title says, why is Tokyo Ghoul's second season called √A?

Comment: Probably standing for Root A. "A" standing for Aogiri and "Root" for the root of a tree.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**√A ("root A")** is a reference to and pun on the [Aogiri Tree](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Aogiri_Tree) organization, which is the focus of the second season. "A" is simply the first letter of the organization, and the [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) is a pun on [tree root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root) (since it's the Aogiri *Tree*).

Comment: There is another theory that it's "Route A", since the anime has some deviation at the beginning of the season.

Comment: @nhahtdh Interesting. I could see that being a plausible explanation, too.

Comment: nhahtdh's theory is the one that I have heard.